# Repeated querys to a db with JDBC or dump data to ArrayList and iterate over list whenever I want some data?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, arraylist, dump

I am working on a trade's appointments agenda. The question is that what is better.
When application initialize, dump data from database to an ArrayList and iterate over ArrayList whenever that I want appointments of a day OR execute one query everytime that I want appointments of a day? The database is on localhost.

Java querys are PreparedStatement.

I ask this because when appointments will increase, Iterate over ArrayList is going to be less and less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options based on how big your tables and how scalable you need your system to be.

If you have a pattern in showing the daily appointments, then I suggest you extract that pattern to have a generic solution to show the appointments of a day.

On top of this if you have validations to be running for a selected day, keep it simple and safe in your database, that way the whole point of persistence is not lost also.

Have a look at in memory databases as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I would leave database *processing* and the *cache* the database. I have done some measurements, and these show that processing records in a JVM is quite slow (filter, sort, distinct, group).

This is especially the case, if you are using higher level collections like `ArrayList` in contrast to arrays (like `Customer[]`).

I would not even worry with "remote" databases; in case of localhost databases just give the database more RAM for its cache or work memory, and it's hard to beat the database access planning/cache of a database with Java.

But you should follow the rule to query your database with a *single* SQL statement only. It doesn't really matter how complex that query is, but it's important that your request is done in a single query.

There is another adavantage: You have no cache to deal with explicitly. It's not hard to build caches in Java, but cache synchronization/invalidation can be difficult. So the codebase you have to maintain is much smaller.